# Memory errors with itertools and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, python-itertools

I am trying to generate following stepped sequence pattern but python throws 
**MemoryError**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

Temp = np.linspace(-5,5,pow(2,16))

df = pd.DataFrame([Temp*2] , index=['ColA','ColB']).T

print df

df2 = pd.DataFrame([e for e in itertools.product(df.ColA,df.ColB)],columns=df.columns)

print df2
```

***Errors***

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([e for e in itertools.product(df.ColA,df.ColB)],columns=df.columns)
MemoryError
```

Please let me know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `power=16` and `itertools.product` (yielding the `cartesian product`), you are creating a list of `(2*2)^16=4,294,967,296` `tuples`, or `rows` in your `DataFrame`. Do you want that long a sequence?

```
power = 16
for i in range(power):
    Temp = np.linspace(-5, 5, pow(2, i))
    df = pd.DataFrame([Temp] * 2, index=['ColA','ColB']).T
    print(i, len(df), len(list(product(df.ColA, df.ColB))))

0 1 1
1 2 4
2 4 16
3 8 64
4 16 256
5 32 1024
6 64 4096
7 128 16384
8 256 65536
9 512 262144
10 1024 1048576
11 2048 4194304
12 4096 16777216
13 8192 67108864
14 16384 268435456
...
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to create stepped waveform and do various calculation based on it.

Comment: With`dtype`  `float64`, it would probably take at least 4,294,967,296 * 64 * 2 / (8 * 1024) ~ 67GB of memory.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Infact even though i create this table storing them in excel is not possible as excel can't store more than 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt support.

Comment: You're welcome. Just let me know if you need any further detail of if you find the answer acceptable.